# Passing Guid from Angular Front End to Asp.Net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a CRUD app and when I'm passing Guids from Angular to ASP.NET core but I'm getting a ""Error converting value "" to type 'System.Guid'" when posting . I couldn't find anything helpful around here. Any hints on how to achieve it?

This is my Model in the back end:

```
 public class ArchiveFile
    {
        [Key]       
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ArchiveBoxId")]
        public ArchiveBox ArchiveBox { get; set; }

        public Guid ArchiveBoxId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the front end:

```
export class File {
    id: string; 
    name: string;
    code: string;
    value: number;
    boxId: string; 
}
```

This is the post method in the front end:

```
postFile() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    }
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/files', this.fileFormData, httpOptions)
```

and in the back end:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddFile(ArchiveFile file)
        {


            _archiveFileRepository.AddFile(file);

            await _archiveFileRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetFile", new { id = file.Id }, file);
        }
```

Comment: it looks like the GUID value isn't being passed to the API.  where is it supposed to be passed in this.fileFOrmData ??   if so I would add a console.log or debugger and make sure that this.fileFormData has the Id set correctly

Comment: Hi @PabloAguirredeSouza, have you checked the request and the actual posted data?